# Responsive Nav Bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, mobile

How would I go about creating a responsive nav bar that would also work on mobile devices?

What I need is an anchor that when clicked would push the page to the right hand side and have the nav bar appear on the right. ( Kind of like the way in-which facebook's mobile nav bar works really.)

The best example I can find is [here](http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/SlidePushMenus/) but I cant seem to pick apart the code that only uses the Right Push Menu Button.

Comment: http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/panels/

Comment: thank you for your comment, this is kind of what im looking for but isn't there a lighter weight way in-which to achieve this?

Comment: if you need something very simple the best is to build it yourself. For the animation try [jQuery.Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) for more performance. The rest should be a simple thing like 2 divs, one for the nav one for the content and then either push or whatever can be done on your own

Comment: ideally i would write it in javascript and do something like when the anchor is click it moves all content to the left and reavel the nav bar on the right, i just dont know how to write it is all sadly, i guess im gona have to find a plug-in i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? Obviously it could be styled more beautifully, etc, but the basic structure works.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button id="menuHandle">Menu</button>
```

**CSS:**

```
#menu {
    background-color:#abcdef;
    float:left;
    display:none;
    padding:20px;
}
```

**js (well, jquery)**

```
$('#menuHandle').click(function(){
  $('#menu').fadeToggle();
});
```

JSFiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/U9CT6/

Comment: yeh alot like this thanks! im just wondering if it would push any other content including the button over to the side

Comment: Should do! Here's an updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U9CT6/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try HTML5-Navigation-Menu

Responsive Nav Bar with mobile and tablet

https://github.com/tushgraph/HTML5-Navigation-Menu.git